# How to make transparent shape to make the color more bright

Tags: gimp

How to make a transparent shape for example a rectangle that increase the brightness of background color or other shape like image below. The background color is dark blue, the shape make the color more bright.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add a white shape into a new top layer which has blending mode "Value" or "Overlay". Adjust the layer opacity smaller, if needed.

A white shape has been added:

[image]

The blending mode has been changed to Value, the opacity has been reduced to keep the color possible to produce

[image]

Unfortunately the white shape must have something under. Against transparency it becomes visible as white:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with layers, and blend modes.

[image]

The Background layer is solid colour

Layer 2 is filled light blue, solid colour

Layer 3 has is solid darker blue, with Blending mode set to Pin Light.

Layer 4 is a line filled with a very light blue, Blending mode set to Lightness (LHC)